# Eagle disabling part in PCB

Tags: eaglecad

I have Eagle schematics, which contains ISA connector. Is it possible to mark this part in schematic as "hidden", so it is ignored in PCB editor - not shown and neither routes are not shown for this connector? I do not want to delete this connector in schematic.

Comment: You could edit the Part (or create an alternate "hidden" part) so that the pins are reference only. Do this by removing any sort of trace layer PCB footprint and changing the schematic symbol by replacing the actual PIN with a line. Then when you place that part, it will not have a footprint or traces to route because as far as the router is concerned, it doesn't exist. The footprint outline can always be edited to be invisible, but I believe that as long as there is a directional PIN in the symbol, a trace to it will be routed.

Comment: Here are descriptions to the PIN directions. I don't think any of them will work for what you want... http://blog.ilektronx.com/2012/04/advanced-eagle-layout-tutorial-building.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into "assembly variants." In the board window, look at Edit>Assembly Variants. Click new, name it, and then you can disable parts. That way, they will not show up.

Comment: I assume you mean "Schematics window". The "assembly variants" does not exist on that menu on "board window" view. After adding a new one, checkboxes appears in front of all components. I tried unchecking the ones I want to "hide", but they still show up on the "board window". What am I missing?